# hover over photo wont add transparent div

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a transparent text overlay on top of an image. I've decided that using CSS to add the transparent div would be easiest, but can't figure out why my code isn't working. I changed the opacity of the image when hovering over and set the div containing the text to `visibility:hidden`. I used the `hover`effect to make `visibility:visible`. I just can't get it to work though. please help. Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/3Lx1pyL9/

Here's the html:

```
<div id="chickcontainer">

        <img src="http://animal-dream.com/data_images/chicken/chicken7.jpg"><div class="overlay">chicks</div>
        <img class="chicks" src="https://smittenkitchendotcom.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/piri-piri-chicken.jpg?w=750">
        <img class="chicks" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRzRJV4iLzYh0eqyVG9-OidAW1t24Xa_vmVRX4Qy-WoyMIgpCx6">
    </div>
```

and the css:

```
#chickcontainer img{
    position:relative;
    width:30%;
    height:30%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:2%;
    border-radius:100%;
    border: solid .5px;

}

.overlay{
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    width:20%;
    height:90%;
    top:12%;
    left:7%;
    z-index:0;
}

#chickcontainer img:hover .overlay{
    visibility:visible;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your selector:

```
#chickcontainer img:hover .overlay
```

This selector expects `.overlay` to be a descendent of `img:hover` and images are not able to have descendants at all. In your html, `.overlay` is a sibling that sits **next** to the image.

```
<img src="http://animal-dream.com/data_images/chicken/chicken7.jpg"><div class="overlay">chicks</div>
```

Instead, you should use the "next sibling" `+` selector to select the next element and apply the style to it.

```
#chickcontainer img:hover + .overlay
```

Here's a working example

```css
#chickcontainer img{
    position:relative;
    width:30%;
    height:30%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:2%;
    border-radius:100%;
    border: solid .5px;

}

.overlay{
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    width:20%;
    height:90%;
    top:12%;
    left:7%;
    z-index:0;
}

#chickcontainer img:hover + .overlay{
    visibility:visible;
    z-index:100;
}
```

```html
<div id="chickcontainer">
    <img src="http://animal-dream.com/data_images/chicken/chicken7.jpg"><div class="overlay">chicks</div>
    <img class="chicks" src="https://smittenkitchendotcom.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/piri-piri-chicken.jpg?w=750">
    <img class="chicks" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRzRJV4iLzYh0eqyVG9-OidAW1t24Xa_vmVRX4Qy-WoyMIgpCx6">
</div>
```

Comment: It is also noteworthy that `img` cannot have descendants.

Answer (score 2):

The `.overlay` container has to be a child of the hovered element.

I updated the fiddle so it works. Not good but the mechanism should be clear.

https://jsfiddle.net/3Lx1pyL9/4/

Comment: No extra HTML necessary.

Comment: Yeah, learned that from Soviut. Didn´t know that Until now, Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

As the <img> is not a pair tag , so you can't place any element inside it.

Change

```
#chickcontainer img:hover .overlay
```

to

```
#chickcontainer img:hover + .overlay
```

The element+element selector is used to select elements that is placed immediately after (not inside) the first specified element.

refer : [CSS element+element Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp)